# Lighthouse as RESTful api

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, webserver, lighthouse

I would like to turn Google's lighthouse tool into a service which I can query via HTTP requests (send url address with config and receive report). Any idea how to build it in a scalable way in node.js? Processing of single webpage may take several seconds, so by scalable I mean that multiple GET/POST requests are actually executed in parallel (with some max number of procesess/threads). For example, if I send 10 asynchronous requests, lets say from Python, I will get all responses back after 20 seconds and not after 20*10 seconds.
I am novice in servers and javascript (although I know other programming languages) so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a public API to use for lighthouse?

Comment: There is open source node js library